# How do I drop all constraints from all tables?

Tags: sql-server, ddl, constraint

I want to drop all default constraints, check constraints, unique constraints, primary keys and foreign keys from all tables in a SQL Server database. I know how to get all the constraint names from `sys.objects`, but how do I populate the `ALTER TABLE` part?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the context of such a request? Am wondering how functional dependencies are addressed (i.e. indexed views, cascade events on FKs, and UQs that had IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON).

Comment: @srutzky [It was asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115606/how-to-drop-a-constraint-without-knowing-its-table) but I decided to create a cleaner, canonical version here. Anyway it is a common request, often part of a larger task of cleaning out a database (starting over, cleaning up objects that were mistakenly put into master, etc). I don't see these functional dependencies being impacted by dropping the constraints - in fact I suspect that in most cases the larger picture is truncating or dropping the tables, too. Dropping the constraints first allows that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can derive this information easily by joining `sys.tables.object_id = sys.objects.parent_object_id` for those object types.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
  + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ';'
FROM sys.objects AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON c.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE c.[type] IN ('D','C','F','PK','UQ')
ORDER BY c.[type];

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

`PRINT` is just there for eyeballing, not for copying and pasting the output (if you want to run it, that's what the commented-out `EXEC` is for) - if you have a *lot* of constraints, it may not show the entire script because `PRINT` is limited to 4,000 characters (8kb). In those cases, if you need to validate the entire script, see [this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/) for other ways to validate the script before running. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml, @sql);
```

Once you are happy with the output, uncomment the `EXEC`.

Comment: You might also want to make sure to drop foreign key constraints before primary keys; `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN c.[type] IN ('PK', 'UQ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @Daniel good point, ORDER BY type is probably sufficient until SQL Server introduces new constraint types.

Comment: You can just use a select statement to view rather than print then copy and paste - this seemed to work for me:
`SELECT N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
  + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ';'
FROM sys.objects AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON c.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE c.[type] IN ('D','C','F','PK','UQ')
ORDER BY c.[type];`

Comment: @TheNerdyNerd `PRINT` is just for validation of the first 8K, you could also just change it to `SELECT @sql;` but then you have to give instructions to users to change the default output limit and also change from grid to text so you don't lose CR/LF. Nobody said to use print then copy and paste... there is an EXEC there, commented out for safety, so that you don't have to copy and paste anything (which you still have to do if you just use SELECT directly).

Comment: @AaronBertrand But the point for validation gets cut off at the first 8k. If you use Select '@sql' you have a space in the alter for the next line so this wouldn't be great for a copy and paste. 

If you use the select doesn't that allow by default more of your statements to be viewed as rows and thus no need to change anything in configuration? At least this was for me.

I would like to validate in a SQL query window all statements - as I can sense check the statement about to be run in its fullest form and leverage intellisense etc...

Comment: @TheNerdyNerd you proposed using `SELECT N'ALTER TABLE...'` as a replacement for `PRINT` and copy+paste. How are you going to use the output of `SELECT ` **or** `PRINT` without copy+paste? Again: it's just for spot-checking, and I suggested `PRINT` over `SELECT` simply because with default settings (a) the latter only shows 256 characters and (b) results to grid is useless. If you need to validate the entire script, you're not going to get that from either. If you just `SELECT` and any portion is > 8K, you can't **run** it. `SELECT CONVERT(xml, @sql);` _may_ work, depending on the content.

Comment: @TheNerdyNerd Also not sure I understand your point about the space in the next line. T-SQL doesn't really care about whitespace and you are free to format it however you like. I optimized for presentation here, not eventual output.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Not sure I follow - why is results to grid useless? I can copy 254 rows - with no characters missing - running query as is. Using `PRINT` I need to go to tools and extend limits - also by not pasting into a SQL query window you can spot check but you don't get intellisense to quickly check syntax of your queries being generated too.

Whitespace whilst not being an issue in generating or running scripts but if you are talking about character limits you're adding to those aren't you with the whitespace? My point was to help others that I found the print option to be limiting.

Comment: Print cut off Select not - samples:

`PRINT OUTPUT:`
_...DROP CONSTRAINT [Property_Deal_Detail_Id];
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Property_Deal_Detail] DROP CONSTRAINT [Property_Deal_Detail_Create_Date];
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Property_Deal_Detail] DROP CONSTRAINT [Property_Deal_Detail_Edit_Date];
  ALTER

(240 rows affected)_
`SELECT OUTPUT:`
_...ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address_Link] DROP CONSTRAINT [CLUSTERED_IX_AddressLink];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[__RefactorLog] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK____Refact__D3AEFFDBE12F66C0];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__Address__03BDEBBAC231985D];_

Comment: @TheNerdyNerd SELECT to grid is useless for anything that isn't a one-liner, so it works great for a simple ALTER TABLE with no carriage returns but then you have to change methods if you have any carriage returns in any line. I thought I addressed the limitations of PRINT in my answer handily enough but I expanded on it to be sure.

Answer (score 8):

I started with the accepted answer and modified the structure to use a while loop rather than to build the full sql statement in dynamic sql.  I like this better for several reasons.

The query is not stored in the large @sql variable.  This implementation allows for a Print for each constraint that is dropped for logging purposes in the output.  Execution seemed a little faster in my unit testing.

```
Set NoCount ON

Declare @schemaName varchar(200)
set @schemaName=''
Declare @constraintName varchar(200)
set @constraintName=''
Declare @tableName varchar(200)
set @tableName=''

While exists
(   
    SELECT c.name
    FROM sys.objects AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON c.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE c.[type] IN ('D','C','F','PK','UQ')
    and t.[name] NOT IN ('__RefactorLog', 'sysdiagrams')
    and c.name > @constraintName
)

Begin   
    -- First get the Constraint
    SELECT 
        @constraintName=min(c.name)
    FROM sys.objects AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON c.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE c.[type] IN ('D','C','F','PK','UQ')
    and t.[name] NOT IN ('__RefactorLog', 'sysdiagrams')
    and c.name > @constraintName

    -- Then select the Table and Schema associated to the current constraint
    SELECT 
        @tableName = t.name,
        @schemaName = s.name
    FROM sys.objects AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON c.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE c.name = @constraintName

    -- Then Print to the output and drop the constraint
    Print 'Dropping constraint ' + @constraintName + '...'
    Exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @schemaName + N'].[' + @tableName + N'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @constraintName + ']')
End

Set NoCount OFF
```